# Adjusting the width of legend for continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a script below to illustrate my question:

```
temp.df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,z=1:100,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
chart <- ggplot(data=temp.df,aes(x=x,y=y))
chart <- chart + geom_line(aes(colour=z))
chart <- chart + scale_colour_continuous(low="blue",high="red")
chart <- chart + theme(legend.position="bottom")
# so far so good, but I think the legend positioned at bottom with such a small size is a waste of space, so I want to "widen" it using the line below...
chart <- chart + guides(colour=guide_legend(keywidth=5,label.position="bottom"))
# oops, it changed to legend for categorical variable
```

How can I widen the "continuous variable" legend positioned at bottom?

Comment: Since @Didzis gave the answer you were looking for, I thought I'd give the link to the possible attributes you could set. [**Here it is**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of function `guides()` you should use the function `theme()` and set the `legend.key.width=`

```
temp.df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,z=1:100,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
chart <- ggplot(data=temp.df,aes(x=x,y=y))
chart <- chart + geom_line(aes(colour=z))
chart <- chart + scale_colour_continuous(low="blue",high="red")
chart <- chart + theme(legend.position="bottom")
chart <- chart + theme(legend.key.width=unit(3,"cm"))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `guide_colourbar` instead of `guide_legend` in your code :

```
temp.df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,z=1:100,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
chart <- ggplot(data=temp.df,aes(x=x,y=y))
chart <- chart + geom_line(aes(colour=z))
chart <- chart + scale_colour_continuous(low="blue",high="red")
chart <- chart + theme(legend.position="bottom")
chart + guides(colour=guide_colourbar(barwidth=30,label.position="bottom"))
```

[image]